# Populate and bind an NSTableView to multiple array controllers

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I have an API provided NSArray with a bunch of content objects – we'll call this `acquiredFruit` – and an empty NSMutableArray called `likedFruit`.

I've created NSArrayControllers for both arrays and bound my TableView to `acquiredFruit.arrangedObjects`. The first column of the tableView is bound to `arrangedObjects.name` and correctly shows all the delicious fruit.

I've created a second column with a checkbox – when the user fills the box I'd like to add the fruit to my `likedFruit` array. Unchecking the box should remove the fruit object from the `likedFruit` array.

**Essentially I'd like my NSTableView to join between two array controllers.** I have a feeling I should be making a single separate controller for this, but I'm unsure how to approach the problem.

I should also mention that I'm aware I could iterate through my array and construct another object with the fields I need, but my goal is to do this by using bindings, if possible.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you displaying these likedFruits in another table, or do just need them to be in an array?

Comment: I want the checked state of the row in my acquiredFruits bound table to represent the fruit's presence in likedFruits - I don't need another tableVlew, but I'm planning on iterating through likedFruits elsewhere in the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use one array controller.

You can have an attribute on Fruit called `liked`. Now your "liked" checkbox column is connected to `arrangedObjects.liked`. Later, when you want to determine the set of all liked fruits, you can query your fruits array:

```
NSArray * likedFruits = [ allFruitsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[ NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"liked = YES"] ] ;
```

If in another part of your UI you are displaying only liked fruit, you can set your array controller's filterPredicate to the predicate above to get just those fruits.

EDIT: Let's say NSFruit is provided via someone else's API. Let's use the "General Technique for Adding Properties to Someone Else's Class":

```
@interface NSFruit (Liking)
@property ( nonatomic ) BOOL liked ;
@end

@implementation NSFruit (Liking)

-(BOOL)liked
{
    return [ objc_getAssociatedObject( self, "_abliked" ) boolValue ] ;
}

-(void)setLiked:(BOOL)b
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject( self, "_abliked", [ NSNumber numberWithBool:b ], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC ) ;
}

@end
```

(I've written this same code for like 100 posts recently!)

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. And if NSFruit is actually an object given to my by a third party API? Do I need to wrap it or write a category? I suppose I could create my own ABFruit…

Comment: I've edited my post to show adding "liked" as a property to NSFruit via a category...

Comment: Cool, I'm actually familiar with Categories, I'm just always hesitant to use them. I hear conflicting answers on when this appropriate.

Comment: ok cool. personally, I avoid subclassing when I can. For example, I rarely make custom views, I just compose collections of exiting views. I find this helps avoid "painting yourself into a corner" architecturally, saves on refactoring, keeps your class hierarchy flat, etc. I'd like to hear people's reasons for when *not* to use categories, because I think those are rare cases indeed.. I guess any more is better left to a chat discussion?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at my Xcode computer right now, so i can't test this, but it seems like you don't really need another array controller, but just another array to hold the likedFruits.  I think you need to create an array of dictionaries from your acquiredFruits array that would have one key for the fruit name and another key with a bool value for whether the check box is checked --this bool would be bound to your second column. I'm not sure about the next step on how to tell the likedFruit array that it need to add a new fruit -- I think the check box could have an action method that you could use to have the likedFruit array add the object in the row where the check box was clicked.

After Edit:

Here is an example of how to do what I suggested. I take an array of fruits and turn it into an array of dictionaries (called theData) that include a key for the value of your check box (In IB the content array of the array controller is bound to theData, and the columns are bound to Array Controller.arrangedObjects.fruitName and Array Controller.arrangedObjects.isLiked). checkChanged is an IBAction connected to the check box (but note the sender is actually the table view), and I use the value of the check box to determine whether to add a fruit to likedFruits or delete one. I put one more method, connected to a button just to check the values in likedFruits.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.theData = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.likedFruit =[NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *acquiredFruits = @[@"Apple",@"Orange",@"Pear",@"Peach"];
    for (NSString *aFruit in acquiredFruits) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:aFruit,@"fruitName",[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],@"isLiked", nil];
        [self.theData addObject:[dict mutableCopy]];
    }
    self.theData = _theData;
   // NSLog(@"%@",self.theData);
}



-(IBAction)checkChanged:(NSTableView *)sender { //connected to the button cell in the table view (but sender is the table view)
    NSString *theFruit = [[self.controller.arrangedObjects objectAtIndex:sender.clickedRow ] valueForKey:@"fruitName"];
    BOOL doWeLikeIt = [[[self.controller.arrangedObjects objectAtIndex:sender.clickedRow] valueForKey:@"isLiked"] boolValue];
    if (doWeLikeIt) {
        [self.likedFruit addObject:theFruit];
    }else{
        [self.likedFruit removeObject:theFruit];
    }
}

-(IBAction)logLikedFruits:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"%@",self.likedFruit);
}
```

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate a bit?

Comment: Thanks @rdelmar, this answer makes sense. It's a great example of composing an array controller from multiple sources. I think the Category approach fits better with my use case and let's me bind to an API-provided array. I'll definitely keep this in mind for other scenarios!

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean by an API provided array. While my method doesn't allow you to bind directly to the array, it does allow you to create a new array of dictionaries from that array.